# How can I fix my custom Sublime Text syntax highlighting?

Tags: regex, yaml, sublimetext, sublime-syntax

I'm trying to create a very basic `.sublime-syntax` file to understand how the YAML-based definitions work and eventually create a full definition (the language is an old version of UnrealScript - definitions exist for this language already but I'm doing this as more of a learning exercise).

The first thing I'm trying to tackle is the declaration of variables, which can exist in a few different forms:

```cs
var int myInt;
var int myIntA, myIntB, myIntC;
var() int myInt;
var(foo) int myInt;
```

My syntax file currently looks like:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: UnrealScript

file_extensions:
  - uc

scope: source.uscript

variables:
  valid_variable_name: '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]{0,}'
  valid_type_name: '{{valid_variable_name}}'

contexts:
  main:
    - match: ;
      scope: punctuation.terminator.statement.empty.uscript

    - match: '(?i)\bvar'
      scope: storage.variable.var.uscript
      push:
        - meta_scope: meta.variable.assignment
        - match: \(
          scope: punctuation.variable.property.begin.uscript
          push:
            - match: '{{valid_variable_name}}'
              scope: variable.parameter.uscript
            - match: ''
              pop: 1
        - match: \)
          scope: punctuation.variable.property.end.uscript
        - match: '{{valid_type_name}}(?=\s+)'
          scope: storage.type.uscript
          push:
            - match: '{{valid_variable_name}}'
              scope: variable.other.readwrite.uscript
              pop: 1
        - match: ;
          pop: 1
```

This seems to highlight things correctly, but let's say I start typing this and haven't yet added a semi-colon:

```cs
var int myInt, somethingElse
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The variable name `somethingElse` is assigned the `storage.type.uscript` scope but I want it to be assigned `variable.other.readwrite.uscript` - what am I missing?

Side note: I'm aware of named contexts but am using anonymous contexts for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `somethingElse` is scoped as `storage.type.uscript` is because it is still in the context with the meta scope `meta.variable.assignment`. (It would be much easier to discuss if the contexts were named btw...) So it sees `{{valid_type_name}}(?=\s+)` as matching `somethingElse` (assuming a newline after it and not typing exactly at EOF).

The simple solution here is to scope the variables after a comma correctly - so instead of popping after assigning scope `variable.other.readwrite.uscript`, only pop at semi-colon for example.

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: UnrealScript

file_extensions:
  - uc

scope: source.uscript

variables:
  valid_variable_name: '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]{0,}'
  valid_type_name: '{{valid_variable_name}}'

contexts:
  main:
    - match: ;
      scope: punctuation.terminator.statement.empty.uscript

    - match: '(?i)\bvar'
      scope: storage.variable.var.uscript
      push:
        - meta_scope: meta.variable.assignment
        - match: \(
          scope: punctuation.variable.property.begin.uscript
          push:
            - match: '{{valid_variable_name}}'
              scope: variable.parameter.uscript
            - match: ''
              pop: 1
        - match: \)
          scope: punctuation.variable.property.end.uscript
        - match: '{{valid_type_name}}(?=\s+)'
          scope: storage.type.uscript
          push:
            - match: '{{valid_variable_name}}'
              scope: variable.other.readwrite.uscript
            - match: ','
              scope: punctuation.separator.sequence.uscript
            - match: (?=;)
              pop: 1
        - match: ;
          scope: punctuation.terminator.uscript
          pop: 1
```

Comment: Makes sense; thank you!